# Proving $\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{+} \mid x_1 x_2 \geq 1\}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

This is so called a hyperbolic set

$$\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{+} \mid x_1 x_2 \geq 1\}$$

We proceed to prove that it is convex by showing that a convex combination of points (a line segment) will lie in the set

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2)$, $y = (y_1, y_2)$ and $x \geq y$ in the elementwise sense

Then set:
$z = \theta(x_1,x_2) + (1-\theta)(y_1, y_2)$

$z = (y_1,y_2) + \theta(x_1 - y_1, x_2 - y_2)$

Clearly, any $z_1,z_2 \in z$ lies in the hyperbolic set (i.e. $z_1z_2 \geq 1$)

How do we proceed to prove the case when $x \not \geq y$ in the elementwise sense?

Comment: You miss some requirement since now $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are both in the set, but the origin is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ in our set, and $\alpha \in [0,1]$. We need to show that $\alpha (x_1,y_1) + (1-\alpha) (x_2, y_2)$ is in our set, *i.e.* that $$\alpha^2 x_1y_1 + (1-\alpha)^2 x_2y_2 + \alpha(1-\alpha)(x_1y_2+x_2y_1) \geq 1$$

**Hint**: notice that $x_1y_1 \geq 1, x_2y_2 \geq 1$ and prove that $x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 \geq 2$ to conclude.

Answer (score 4):

Say $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so our set is $\{(x,y): y\geq f(x)\}$. We know that $f(x)$ is convex, that is for $0\leq\theta\leq 1$ $$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\leq \theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y).$$

Now take $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in the set. In other words $y_1\geq f(x_1)$ and $y_2\geq f(x_2)$. For $0\leq\theta\leq 1$
$$\theta y_1+(1-\theta)y_2\geq\theta f(x_1)+(1-\theta)f(x_2)\geq f(\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_2)$$ so it is in the set.

Comment: Can you help me clarify some confusion?  The domain of your example is $\mathbb{R}$ and the domain in the question is $\mathbb{R^2}$.  Why are you using a different domain for your proof ?  and how does it relate to the domain in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your hyperbolic set is defined by the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 1\\ 1 & x_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_2$$

which, using [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), produces the following conjunction of (non-strict) inequalities

$$x_1 \geq 0 \land x_2 \geq 0 \land x_1 x_2 - 1 \geq 0$$

Hence, the hyperbolic set is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, *convex*.

---

[convex-analysis](/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [spectrahedra](/questions/tagged/spectrahedra)

Comment: thanks for the answer